# Java thread sync issue

Tags: java

This is another issue where my code doesn't work, until I add a print statement into the code, which causes everything to work fine. I've been struggling to get my head around thread synchronization lately but its been slow progress. I want a quick fix that can do whatever the print statement does so I can carry on with this. The context is a thread that runs in the server, constantly checking for newly registered users. If the new user doesn't currently exist in the databse, this thread will add it in.

```
class RecieveThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Message msg;
            try {
                msg = comms.receiveUserMessage();
                User newUser;
                newUser = (User)msg.getContents();

                //System.out.println(newUser.getID() + ": " + newUser.getFN());

                for(User user : existingUsers) {
                    if(newUser.getFN().equals(user.getFN()) && newUser.getLN().equals(user.getLN())) {
                        existingUsers.add(user);
                        System.out.println("added: " + newUser.getFN());
                    }
                }
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Comms {
    public Message receiveUserMessage() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        User user;
        File userMailbox = new File("UserMailbox.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(userMailbox);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        user = (User)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

        return new UserMessage(user);
    }
}

public abstract class Message {
    abstract Object getContents();
}

class UserMessage extends Message {
    private User user;

    public UserMessage(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getContents() {
        return this.user;
    }
}


import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {
    private String fn;
    private String ln;
    private int id;
    private char[] pwd;
    private static int userCount = 0;

    public User(String fn, String ln, char[] pwd) {
        this.fn = fn;
        this.ln = ln;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.id = ++userCount;
    }

    public String getFN() {
        return fn;
    }

    public String getLN() {
        return ln;
    }

    public char[] getPwd() {
        return this.pwd;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

#### Stacktrace:

```
java.io.EOFException

at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readTypeString(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at Comms.receiveUserMessage(Comms.java:40)
at ServerPanel$RecieveThread.run(ServerPanel.java:32)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at Comms.receiveUserMessage(Comms.java:40)
at ServerPanel$RecieveThread.run(ServerPanel.java:32)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at Comms.receiveUserMessage(Comms.java:40)
at ServerPanel$RecieveThread.run(ServerPanel.java:32)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What exactly isn't it doing that it should be, or what is it doing that it shouldn't be?

Comment: what is existingUsers? a Set? you search for an user in the collection, and you try to add it when you find it???

Comment: Without the print statement, it throws a EOFException.
Edit: was meant to drop a line..

Comment: @francescoforesti  nope, in that case you call add for any existing, non-same, user; he needs equals() on User, and just add() if it is a set.

Comment: With the print statement, it adds a new user to the List existingUsers, the for loop works fine, just the program breaks down before it reaches that bit if I don't include a print statement.

Comment: @Squiffy Well, if that's an EOFException, just flush and close the stream (or writer, or whatever you are using).

Comment: @Squiffy before crashing your head against threads, I'd suggest you really slow down and understand some more basic concepts

Comment: you need to show all the relevant code, there are variables here that are important but not shown what they are, you also **must** show stacktraces when that is what you are trying to fix.

Comment: Its an ObjectInputStream in the method receiveUserMessage(), and there is a close statement that method. The exception isn't thrown with the print statement though. I just want to simulate the print statement so that the code works but without printing to the console.

Comment: do not answer in the comments **edit** your question with the relevant information, this will get closed pretty quickly if you do not

Comment: Read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you are running afoul of *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Still no stacktrace? Why? Also this has absolutely nothing with *synchronization* of threads unless that `comms` object is shared and it is not threadsafe, which it does not appear to be.

Comment: Try putting a sleep statement in place of the print statement.  Do you still have the same issue?  Print statements take a relatively long time to run, so having one in there may inadvertently cause your code to reach a 'safe' state.

Comment: Maybe someone thinks all the things that are submitted as answers are guessing and mostly asking questions which should be comments because of the missing code and stacktrace? And maybe someone else things most of them suggesting more guessing about how to fix this are just plain wrong, but that is just me guessing about others opinions as well. Either way downvote shaming by and guessing at intention are both **not constructive**.

Comment: @Matthieu - See this [meta-discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive).

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It was pretty obvious in this case (by the change in rep) that the Squiffy downvoted all the answers on this page.  But the question's premise is wrong.  Threading is not the issue - the infinite unthrottled loop is.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop does two things forever.

1. Read a message off the disk.
2. Check (incorrectly) the new user against a list.

As there is no resting (`Thread.sleep()` or some form of blocking access) in any of these the loop just spins, never letting any other thread have a [time-slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking).

Adding the `println` (which is a blocking method) allows other threads a look-in on the system.

Your mistake in checking the user list - imagine what will happen if the `existingUsers` list is empty.

Remember that Java implements [Cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking) on a PC with only one core so all threads must give time to others at regular intervals.

It is likely that the message file either does not exist or is empty.

Comment: He'd be better off without the while loop, and just execute ReceiveThread in a ScheduledExecutor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a couple things:

1) Remove the while loop from your ReceiveThread class.  Then, where you submit it to a thread pool, use a scheduled one instead, something like:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

ReceiveThread rt = new ReceiveThread();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(rt, 0, YOUR_RATE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will cause it to execute periodically, so you won't have an unchecked loop spinning.

2) For debugging, disable the thread pool and just call ReceiveThread directly instead.  Ex:

```
ReceiveThread rt = new ReceiveThread();
rt.run();
```

Then you can more easily step through and figure out the exception if needed.

In any case, wrap the `ois.readObject()` call in a try/catch block to handle the EOFException.

Comment: One angry lad I guess... I'll upvote others' answers to "correct misconduct" (though definitely not the thing to do, I hope someone will do it for mine also, as I believe it actually *is* the answer to the problem...)

Comment: ... and too bad I can't upvote twice because your solution is also interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment saying a sleep statement 'fixes' it just like a print statement, my guess is that `existingUsers` is the problem.  In your code above you're not doing anything to make it thread-safe.  You need something along the lines of:

```
synchronized (existingUsers)
{
    existingUsers.add(user);
}
```

You need to do this every time you want to modify `existingUsers` other than when you initialize it. [Here's a brief entry on `synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).  It's more complicated than I'm stating here, but this is a good place to start.

The thing is, print statements take a *loooong* time.  At least, from the computer's perspective.  So by having a print statement, you're essentially delaying the execution of the code below.  And in your program, this delay seems to be enough to make things run smoothly.  I suspect that something is happening with `existingUsers` elsewhere, but this something happens only once and it happens very early on.  By having the delay, you pass over whatever this happens to be and it never causes a problem.

It's common for multi-threaded exceptions to be really difficult to decipher.  You're getting an `EOFException` but that might be a red herring.  If you were having problems reading the file, I'd expect that exception every time you run it - not just when a print/sleep statement is in there.

Comment: I believe this is a multi-threaded issue, however your latest suggestion hasn't made a difference, as the EOFException is still getting thrown, I've tried putting the synchronized statement in other places in the code, but haven't found the fix yet. I'm content with the sleep statement for now however, while aware my code isn't optimal..

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read your `UserMailbox.txt` file while it is still being written by an `ObjectOutputStream` not shown in the code you gave. Pulling on it endlessly in the `while` loop causes the problem, and the delay incurred by the `System.out.println()` is enough for the "pushing" thread to finish writing the file, which becomes ok to read from.

Try to implement a *synchronization* mechanism to tell your thread that the file has been fully written and is safe to read. If you can't implement such, at least *wait* for the file to stop being modified before reading it:

```
File f = new File("UserMailbox.txt");
long t0 = f.lastModified(), t;
Thread.sleep(100);
while ((t = f.lastModified()) != t0) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    t0 = t;
}
```

That ugly hack will tell you the file is complete. But you should definitely have another mechanism of telling it is ready (e.g send a message).